# JS ticker counter play once, only when in viewport

Tags: javascript

Objective - user scrolls down, ticker plays once when is comes into the viewport.

currently, it plays every single scroll.
Scrolls into frame, plays. User is suitably impressed. scrolls again, plays again. User rolls eyes at ticker.

I'm getting lost in the nesting of the code.
(JS is not my best language)

```
<div id="ticker">    <h2>Here is an impressive number</h2>
   <div class="counter-container">
            <div class="counter">
               
            <h2>    <span id="count">550</span>,000+ </h2>
               
            </div>
</div>
<h2>impressed you are!</h2>
</div>


// Get it's position in the viewport
var ticker = document.querySelector(".counter-container");
var bounding = ticker.getBoundingClientRect();

// Log the results
console.log(bounding);
// {
//  height: 118,
//  width: 591.359375,
//  top: 137,
//  bottom: 255,
//  left: 40.3125,
//  right: 631.671875
// }
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};
// did we do the thing?
if (window.loopCount == null) {
    window.loopCount = 1;
}
if (window.loopCount < 2) { 
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
 
        if (isInViewport(ticker)) { // does the thing when in view
            function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
                // assumes integer values for start and end
                
                var obj = document.getElementById(id);
                var range = end - start;
                // no timer shorter than 50ms (not really visible any way)
                var minTimer = 50;
                // calc step time to show all interediate values
                var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
                
                // never go below minTimer
                stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
                
                // get current time and calculate desired end time
                var startTime = new Date().getTime();
                var endTime = startTime + duration;
                var timer;
            
                function run() {
                    var now = new Date().getTime();
                    var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
                    var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
                    obj.innerHTML = value;
                    if (value == end) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                }
                
                timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
                run();
            }
            
            animateValue("count", 550, 850, 2000); // parameters - adjust the first number and the second number - third number is how long it takes in milliseconds
            }
    }
, false); // if ticker is not in the viewport, do nothing
}
```

added a window.loopCount but it is not counting or working

Comment: Your event is firing every time you scroll and as long as the ticker is in the viewport your logic is firing. You may want to remove the event listener at the end of your logic so that it won't fire again. You'll need to keep a reference to your handler function (either give it a name or assign it to a variable) so you can pass it to removeEventListener.

Comment: The counter doesn't play at all in your example. And I want to make sure about the functionality you are looking for: you want a counter that counts from `start` (for example `550`) to `end` (for example `850`), adding `1` to each count step (so `551`, `552`, `553`... etc.), with each timestep happening every `duration` milliseconds (so for example if `duration = 2000`, every count step happens every 2 seconds), and that perform the counting only if it's visible in the viewport. Is this all correct? What do you mean with 'intermediate values'?